# Unable to Access Barometer (BMP180) using Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, io, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a [BMP180](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1603) barometer which I'd like to read using Python on a Raspberry Pi.

I've followed the [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-bmp085-with-raspberry-pi/overview) and have been successful in readING data using `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` but I get an error when I attempt to run `simpletest.py` in the [Adafruit Python BMP](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BMP) library.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ sudo python examples/simpletest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/simpletest.py", line 37, in <module>
    sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_BMP-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/Adafruit_BMP/BMP085.py", line 68, in __init__
    self._load_calibration()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_BMP-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/Adafruit_BMP/BMP085.py", line 71, in _load_calibration
    self.cal_AC1 = self._device.readS16BE(BMP085_CAL_AC1)   # INT16
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 195, in readS16BE
    return self.readS16(register, little_endian=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 172, in readS16
    result = self.readU16(register, little_endian)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-0.9.3-py2.7.egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 159, in readU16
    result = self._bus.read_word_data(self._address,register) & 0xFFFF
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I've also tried using Adafruit's [Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code) library but I get a similar I/O related error.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/Adafruit_BMP085 $ sudo python Adafruit_BMP085_example.py
Error accessing 0x77: Check your I2C address
Error accessing 0x77: Check your I2C address
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case? I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

Comment: Are you sure you followed the tutorial, may be something wrong with wiring as I see on the tutorial lot of warnings about wiring ?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty confident that the wiring is right. "sudo i2cdetect -y 1" seems to work fine which leads me to believe it's right, however, I will double check.

Comment: Yea...but you need to make sure not to violate those warnings after the `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` step !

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the warnings on the next page of the tutorial (like below). Yes, I can confirm the sensor is looked up to 3.3v pin (not 5v). I appreciate your input; if you're aware of any specific changes them let me know. https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-bmp085-with-raspberry-pi/hooking-everything-up

Comment: Does your Pi detect your I2C board at address `0x77` with `i2cdetect` command?

Comment: Can you please, post the output of `i2cdetect` command?

Comment: did u manage to solve your issue?